Losing adb connection after adb root
Hello Android Enthusiasts, I am unsure about the effects of the adb root command on the connection to the device and I would be glad if somebody could clarify the expected behavior.
Sometimes after executing adb root the connection seems to be completely lost to the device because I get a device <ip> not found error if I try to execute a command afterwards. I could also confirm this with adb devices.
Since this behavior does not always occur after executing adb root I am unsure if this is a bug in my (not-latest) adb version or if I always should connect to the device again before continuing my work.
Thank you very much for your help!
Additional informations:

Connection: ADB over USB
Host-OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Host-ADB: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 28.0.2-debian
Device-OS: Android 13
Device-ADB: Android Debug Bridge Daemon version 1.0.41


Are you using ADB over USB, or via Wi-Fi? What operating system are you running ADB on? What Android version, and which Android device?

@JohnDallman I added more details about the devices and software versions.

My guess is that restarting the on-device adb daemon failed (check logcat via app e.g. termux) and thus you lose adb connection. May be the adbd does not allow to be executed with rot permissions. I am surprised that adb root worked at all. Normally adb refuses to execute this command. May be the adbd version in your ROM is defect. Is this a self-compiled AOSP ROM you use?

@Robert Thank you for the suggestion. I will try this once i encounter the error again. Yes it is a self-compiled AOSP for a non-smartphone device.
